# generating videos in C

Tags: c, video

I'm looking for advice on how to generate videos in C. The main issues I'll be dealing with are

Must be open source, would prefer BSD type license but GPL is acceptable

Must be reasonably well documented (I'm looking at you FFMPEG)

Must be able to generate a non-compressed video

Must be able to draw each frame

Should be able to set the frame rate (though of course I can just make n identical frames)

My toolkit is the GNU development system on UNIX like systems (Linux, OS X, Cygwin, ...)

Having said that, I'm picky about these requirements because if I don't have them I know I can pretty easily generate the individual frames with libgd and use ffmpeg commands to output a video. The point is that I'd rather be able to draw them and generate the video entirely in my C code. Even better would be to be able to provide the library in my own source (BSD license) so that my users don't need to worry about getting things installed on their particular platform.

I'm not set on a video codec other than the availability of non-compressed video (I'm visualizing changes in simulated rotational spectroscopy as rotational parameters or other variables like temperature change). Advice on a particular codec welcome.

Comment: Video generation and handling is a complex business. You cannot expect from FFMPEG that they write a compendium about video. I find FFMPEG reasonably documented. I suggest to invest half a year of learning before throwing away FFMPEG.

Comment: @Nalpy: while I appreciate that video is complex there are two issues, 1) my thesis will be due by then and 2) I'm trying to *use* as opposed to *understand*. 

ffmpeg has lots of great documentation for using it from the command line, which I can use fine; but the libraries are poorly documented. Yes, I can walk through the examples and source code, but my time is better spent elsewhere. I have a solution that works for now, my question was on the existence of a better (by my valuation) solution. It may be that a better solution does not exist, and that's fine.